# Do we perform division by zero while finding the derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Please have a look at this example,

Finding the derivative of the function $f(x) = x^2 :$

$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{(x + \Delta x) - (x)}$

$=$ $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{(x+\Delta x)^2 - (x)^2}{(x + \Delta x) - (x)}$

$=$ $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{(x^2+2x\Delta x + \Delta x^2) - x^2}{x + \Delta x - x}$

$=$ $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{x^2+2x\Delta x + \Delta x^2 - x^2}{\Delta x}$

$=$ $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{2x\Delta x + \Delta x^2}{\Delta x}$

$=$ $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta x(2x + \Delta x)}{\Delta x}$

$=$ $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} 2x + \Delta x$

$=$ $2x$

**From the last two lines**(above),

$\Rightarrow$ $2x + \Delta x = 2x$

$\Rightarrow$ $\Delta x = 0$

If what I've done is correct, then aren't we performing division by zero while evaluating the limit ? But how can this be possible ?

I've started to learn Calculus just recently. So maybe this confusion is due to my lack of understanding of the concept.
Actually I'm still not clear about what is limit.

So, please give a detailed and intuitive explanation of the limiting process.

Comment: (Almost) every single $\Rightarrow$ here should have been $=$

Comment: The last two lines say $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}2x+\Delta x=2x$ and **not** $2x+\Delta x=2x$.

Comment: By assumption $\Delta x$ is non-zero, so that must mean you cheated somewhere..

Comment: Similar questions have been asked *many* times already: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+derivative+division+by+zero

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $\Delta x$ approaches $0$; it is never equal to $0$. This means that we do not need to worry about division by $0$ in order to find the derivative.

Comment: What's the difference between approaching to zero and being exactly zero ? If the limit is what the function approaches zero then, how can we get a definite answer. Because we can always approach more and more closer to zero and each time we approach closer than before we should get a different result.